# Issue in jQuery scroll in Chrome,Opera & safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, scroll

I am trying to add a fadeto effect for one div based on the scroll and following is the code for same

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
         $(window).scroll(function() {
            var currpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(currpos < 199)
            {
                if(currpos > 100)
                {
                    alert('100');
                    //$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.8,function(){});
                }
            }
            else if(currpos < 299)
            {
                if(currpos > 200)
                {
                    alert('200');
                    //$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.6,function(){});
                }
            }
            else if(currpos < 399)
            {
                if(currpos > 300)
                {
                    alert('300');
                    //$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.4,function(){});
                }
            }
            else if(currpos < 499)
            {
                if(currpos > 400)
                {
                    alert('400');
                    //$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.2,function(){});
                }
            }
            else if(currpos < 599)
            {
                if(currpos > 500)
                {
                    alert('500');
                    //$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.1,function(){});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("WOW");   
            }
     });
});
</script>
```

The issue is that this code works fine in Firefox and IE. But not in Chrome, Safari & Opera. Also, the code works perfectly fine when I drag the scrollbar but not when I use the mousewheel.

Any help regarding this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that could reproduce this problem?  coz i can't [see this one](http://jsfiddle.net/twuhB/)

Comment: You can just scroll the result area. You will see that in chrome, only the last else statement is being executed and not the previous if else statement are.

Where as if you check this in firefox by scrolling the result area, you will see that the alerts are given for every position i.e 100, 200, 300, etc. So, the scroll is not working in Chrome

Comment: which Chrome in what platform are you using? my chrome 29 in os x seems executed the correct block

Comment: You mean you are getting the alerts for 100, 200 ,etc in chrome? And I am using Chrome in Windows & and is latest version

Comment: nope, it's 100, 100, 100... until the `scrollTop` match the second `if` statement. if you want 100,200, you should mannuly deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to replicate your problem as follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
         $(window).scroll(function() {
            var currpos = $(window).scrollTop();
.
.
.
    }
```

And found that it working perfectly on all browser, please try to rpelace your jQuery file with the one added above.

Hope this helps.

---

this is the complete page that is working fine on my system

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
$(window).scroll(function() {
var currpos = $(window).scrollTop();
alert(currpos);
if(currpos < 199)
{
if(currpos > 100)
{
alert('100');
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.8,function(){});
}
}
else if(currpos < 299)
{
if(currpos > 200)
{
alert('200');
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.6,function(){});
}
}
else if(currpos < 399)
{
if(currpos > 300)
{
alert('300');
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.4,function(){});
}
}
else if(currpos < 499)
{
if(currpos > 400)
{
alert('400');
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.2,function(){});
}
}
else if(currpos < 599)
{
if(currpos > 500)
{
alert('500');
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.1,function(){});
}
}
else
{
alert("WOW");   
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="height:2000px;">
</body>
</html>
```

copy paste and try once.